# How can I parse an XML file from a URL and save specific tags to a Text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to parse an XML file two ways, but I can't seem to get either working.  I think both methodologies are pretty close, but something is off, and I don't know what.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

wp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=13&stats=1') # define XML location
pw = wp.read()
#print(pw)

tree = ET.parse(pw)
root = tree.getroot()
#print(root)
with open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\my_text_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('ID\n')
for first_heading in root.findall('items'):
    ID = first_heading.find('ratings').find('usersrated').text
    line_to_write = ID + '\n'
    with open('C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\my_text_file.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(line_to_write)
```

Result: no error; nothing happens at all.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

wp = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.boardgamegeek.com/xmlapi2/thing?id=13&stats=1') # define XML location
pw = wp.read()
output_file_path = 'C:\\Users\\Excel\\Desktop\\my_text_file.txt'
f = open(output_file_path, 'wb')
print(f)
f.write('ID\n')

tree = ET.parse(pw)
root = tree.getroot()

for pa in root.iter('items'):
    ArticleID = pa.find('ratings/usersrated').text
    f.write(ArticleID+'\n')
f.close()
```

Result: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

I am using Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this...

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('C:\\path_to_file\\Recon.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for neighbor in root.iter('outputColumn'):
    # we are searching for this string ... '<outputColumn refId='...
    #print(neighbor.attrib) ... to confirm output
    line_to_write = str(neighbor.attrib)
    with open('C:\\path_to_file\\my_text_file.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(line_to_write)
```

This link below is very helpful.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser